# mapping of array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, array-map

I am trying to map array in react but it is not working.How can i map the element.It shows **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')**
Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
import {useCollection} from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";
import {db,storage} from "../firebases";
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import Post from "./Post";

const Posts = ({posts,myId}) => {
  
 const [realPost, loading, error] = useCollection(
   db.collection("posts").orderBy("timestamp","desc")
 );

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    

   realPost?.docs.map((ele,index)=>{
ele.data().postImages.map((urls,i)=>{
    urls[i].map((url,j)=>{
        console.log("index" + j);
    console.log("image"+url)
    })
    
})  
})

  },[])
```

Here is data structure in firebase firestore

```
  postImage
    0
    url
    0 "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebook-clone-1870b.appspot.com/o/posts%2FScreenshot%20(4).png?alt=media&token=7c4bfce4-3c67-4ddf-ab2e-ac884cef3393"
    1 "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebook-clone-1870b.appspot.com/o/posts%2FScreenshot%20(3).png?alt=media&token=f36a86f2-0fa0-44ae-b85f-86cc5d8da7d0"
    2 "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebook-clone-1870b.appspot.com/o/posts%2FScreenshot%20(1).png?alt=media&token=155761cd-9f2d-4c63-b5c7-c66ec366d721"
    timestamp "2021/10/31 1:00:00 PM"
    userId    38
```

The error is
**

```
realPost?.docs.map((ele,index)=>{
  26 |  ele.data().postImages.map((urls,i)=>{
> 27 |      urls[i].map((url,j)=>{
     |             ^
  28 |          console.log("index" + j);
  29 |      console.log("image"+url)
  30 |      })
```

I get this

```
{url: Array(3)}url: (3) ['https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebo…=media&token=a3bc6df3-e483-44b6-a6a7-7d7dc0a96956', 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebo…=media&token=ca1ad6fb-f68e-4452-a556-7a31d426ca8c', 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebo…=media&token=a3bc6df3-e483-44b6-a6a7-7d7dc0a96956'][[Prototype]]: Object
11:24:46.053 Posts.js:28
 break
11:24:46.059 Posts.js:27 {url: Array(3)}url: (3) ['https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebo…=media&token=a4d35c35-046b-448d-86a3-da5826658e54', 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebo…=media&token=26f4413e-4d5c-407e-9db5-c581e41758f6', 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebo…=media&token=9365b619-aae9-4012-bd85-9d6eb6bb2320'][[Prototype]]: Object
11:24:46.061 Posts.js:28
 break
```

when i execute

```
realPost?.docs.map((ele,index)=>{
    ele.data().postImages.map((urls,i)=>{
        console.log(urls)
        console.log("break")
        })
        
    })
```

I get this

```
 [
  {
    "url": [
      "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebook-clone-1870b.appspot.com/o/posts%2FScreenshot%20(4).png?alt=media&token=a3bc6df3-e483-44b6-a6a7-7d7dc0a96956",
      "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebook-clone-1870b.appspot.com/o/posts%2FScreenshot%20(3).png?alt=media&token=ca1ad6fb-f68e-4452-a556-7a31d426ca8c",
      "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebook-clone-1870b.appspot.com/o/posts%2FScreenshot%20(4).png?alt=media&token=a3bc6df3-e483-44b6-a6a7-7d7dc0a96956"
    ]
  }
]
11:31:42.232 Posts.js:26 [
  {
    "url": [
      "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebook-clone-1870b.appspot.com/o/posts%2FScreenshot%20(4).png?alt=media&token=a4d35c35-046b-448d-86a3-da5826658e54",
      "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebook-clone-1870b.appspot.com/o/posts%2FScreenshot%20(3).png?alt=media&token=26f4413e-4d5c-407e-9db5-c581e41758f6",
      "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/facebook-clone-1870b.appspot.com/o/posts%2FScreenshot%20(4).png?alt=media&token=9365b619-aae9-4012-bd85-9d6eb6bb2320"
    ]
  }

]
```

when i changed my code to

```
realPost?.docs.map((ele,index)=>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ele.data().postImages, null, 2)) 
    })
```

**

Comment: What is the issue exactly?  What did your effect lead as output? Your data structure can be hardly read!

Comment: @tmarwen I want to map the array of url...

Answer (score 2):

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')` , this error arises when you try using the `map` method on a non-array object. Looking at your data structure and mapping of your `postImages` instance, you are likely to want to map the array items of `url`. You should first tap into the `url` property which holds the array, you can then map on this array like below:

```
  realPost?.docs.map((ele,index)=>{
    ele.data().postImages.map((urls,i)=>{
       urls.url.map((url_,j)=>{
         console.log("index" + j);
         console.log("image"+url_) //Changed URL to url_ to avoid name clashes.
    })
```

Note that, you are not returning anything from the `map` function, meaning you'd return an array of `undefined`, however, I'm assuming that you are currently testing and would compute and return something once your issue is fixed.